# Can't upload image to active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, activerecord, blob

I am unabe to store a base64 file using ActiveStorage,I am recieving a base64 string from my client

```
params["image"] = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAREAAABMCAYAAABK84MTAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkl0RVh"
```

and when I try to attach it I get:

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature(ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):
```

I've followed many tutorials, tried decoding it first:

```
decoded_image = Base64.decode64(params["image"])
post.image.attach(decoded_image)
```

As well as removing the data:image/png;base64 part from the string with:

```
decoded_image = Base64.decode64(params["image"]['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
```

And then attaching the image with no success, when I do it directly from a file with:

```
file = open("image.png")
post.image.attach(io: file, filename: "post.png")
```

It works perfectly, so I think that my mistake is during the parsing of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work, but give a try to this approach creating a temporary file with `Tempfile`:

```
encoded_image = params["image"]['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1]
decoded_image = Base64.decode64(encoded_image)

file = Tempfile.new

file.binmode
file.write(decoded_image)
file.rewind

post.image.attach(
  io: file,
  filename: "post.png" # The name of the file should be received from paramaters, as well
)

file.close
file.unlink
```

Comment: It worked :) thanks, I find it really weird that it doesn't work directly, though.